# How to refactor multiple For Loops into one?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How can you refactor this function? I feel like a nested for loop would work but I haven't figured out how to make it work.

Here's the function:

```
class Librarian {
  constructor(name, library) {
    this.name = name;
    this.library = library;
  }
findBook(bookTitle) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.library.shelves.fantasy.length; i++){
      if (bookTitle === this.library.shelves.fantasy[i].title){
        this.library.shelves.fantasy.splice(i, 1);
        return `Yes, we have ${bookTitle}`;
      }
    } for (var i = 0; i < this.library.shelves.fiction.length; i++){
      if (bookTitle === this.library.shelves.fiction[i].title){
        this.library.shelves.fiction.splice(i, 1);
        return `Yes, we have ${bookTitle}`;
      }
    } for (var i = 0; i < this.library.shelves.nonFiction.length; i++){
      if (bookTitle === this.library.shelves.nonFiction[i].title){
        this.library.shelves.nonFiction.splice(i, 1);
        return `Yes, we have ${bookTitle}`;
      }
    } return `Sorry, we do not have ${bookTitle}`;
  } 
}
```

Here's my attempt:

```
findBook(bookTitle) {
    for (var j = 0; j < this.libray.shelves.length; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.library.shelves[i].length; i++){
        if (bookTitle === this.library.shelves[j].title){
          this.library.shelves[j].splice(i, 1);
          return `Yes, we have ${bookTitle}`;
        }
      }
    } return `Sorry, we do not have ${bookTitle}`;
}
```

Comment: The `shelves`  appear to be an object not an array, so you'll need to use `for … in` on them.

Comment: @Bergi or use something like `Object.values(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the genres' names and then loop over them:

```js
findBook(bookTitle) {
  const genres = Object.keys(this.library.shelves);
  for (var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
    const genre = genres[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < this.library.shelves[genre].length; j++) {
      if (bookTitle === this.library.shelves[genre][j].title) {
        this.library.shelves[genre].splice(i, 1);
        return `Yes, we have ${bookTitle}`;
      }
    }
  }
  return `Sorry, we do not have ${bookTitle}`;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're really close to getting this to work, you just need to iterate over `this.library.shelves[j].length` in the second for loop instead of `i`. Then you need to access the ith member of the jth shelf.

```
findBook(bookTitle) {
   for (var j = 0; j < this.libray.shelves.length; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.library.shelves[j].length; i++){
         if (bookTitle === this.library.shelves[j][i].title){
            this.library.shelves[j].splice(i, 1);
            return `Yes, we have ${bookTitle}`;
         }
      }
   } 
   return `Sorry, we do not have ${bookTitle}`;
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't see the genre properties on the original code. @marzelin's answer is good.